# create .exe from c# windows application

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, exe

I have a created a visual studio 2010 project that creates a windows form - it references numerous other dll's.

How can I wrap this up in to a single .exe file?

Comment: You want to statically link a DLL?

Comment: You are supposed to create a setup file

Comment: @Rasel: what? The OP wants a single self-contained exe, not an installer...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[ILMerge](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=17630) is what you are looking for with the /t:exe option.

A sample call would look like this:

`ilmerge.exe exefile.exe [dlls-to-internalize.dll ..] /out:exefile-out.exe /t:exe`

A sample usage of using ILMerge to pack up multiple dlls into one and internalizing them can be found here: [dotlesscss buildfile](https://github.com/Tigraine/dotless/blob/master/default.ps1#L87)

More info on using ILMerge can be found on the [ILMerge Website](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ILMerge.aspx).
You can also get it through [NuGet](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/ilmerge) via [Chocolatey](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/chocolatey)

It allows you to pack multiple .NET assemblies into one file by rewriting the references.
You can also internalize your dependencies in case you are supplying a library to someone and don't want to cause dependency conflicts with libraries you are internally using.

Comment: +1, although I have to warn you that ILMerge is finicky about certain DLLs. Generally it's been good though.

Answer (score 1):

As posted ILMerge is one option, another is "SmartAssembly" from RedGate etc.

What all these DO NOT do is internalizing native DLLs - that's a limitation in the Windows API... so any dependency which is a native DLL has to be shipped along with the EXE.

Answer (score -2):

```
 1. Select Configuration Manager and check parameter such as debug/release or x86/new.
    2.Select Release instead of debug from drop down menu near debug button(Visual studio framework).
    3. Click on build and then build yourApplicationName.
    4. Goto Your program folder->bin->release->yourApplicationName.exe.
    5. yourApplicationName.exe is ready to use.
    Thanks
```

Answer (score -3):

Go to Your Application->bin->dubug->yourapplicationname.exe
It is automatically generated but exe from release folder is more faster than the debug due to less information of debug.